# Setting HTTP headers from a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, http-headers, firefox-addon

How can I set HTTP headers in my Firefox extension?

I'll make it so these are only sent while hitting my site so I can detect if the plugin is installed or not and not promote the plugin if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the most compact way I found to make this work:

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService ).addObserver({
    observe : function(subject, topic, data) {
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface( Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel );
            if ( /mysite/.test( channel.originalURI.host ) ) {
                channel.setRequestHeader("x-mysite-extended", "true", false);
            }
    }
},"http-on-modify-request",false);
```

Comment: If you want more info concerning this:

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/

Answer (score 5):

There are a few existing Firefox extensions that modify HTTP headers en route to the server, and at least one of them, [modifyheaders](http://modifyheaders.mozdev.org/), has [open source code](https://github.com/garethhunt/modifyheaders).

Or, of course, there's the relevant page in the Mozilla Developer Center, [Setting HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers).

Comment: Thanks delfuego. I had read that but could not figure out how to get it to work. Finally got a friend to help me out and based on his experience and the docs you suggested we solved it.